# "Predicts the lack of ..." or "predicts a lack of ..."?

Tags: idioms

Which expression is better:

"It predicts the lack of new effects" or "It predicts a lack of new effects"?

Would be happy to hear your opinion.

Comment: It depends on whether you mean _a_ lack of new effects, or _the_ lack of new effects.

Comment: Oh - and what is the difference?

Comment: **A** lack is _any such lack_, while **the** lack is _one specific such lack._ Related: [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/the-confusion-between-the-or-a-article). Welcome to ELU, by the way. Do give some time to take the [tour]. Cheers!